# Laravel 5.6 error reporting

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having a problem with debugging my code in Laravel framework. whenever there is an error, the browser doesn't display a detailed error report like specifying the line number, error type etc..

I made sure that my App_DEBUG variable is set to true and that the file permissions for storage.php is 777. however, the problem isn't solved yet. any idea about the cause and the solution?

[image]

Comment: It's case sensitive. `APP_DEBUG=true`

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here.

Comment: yes sorry, its actually capitalized in the code but I forgot to capitalize it in the question @Ohgodwhy

Answer (score 0):

in you .env write

```
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

and check if you have generated the key

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Comment: thank you, yes i made sure to check these. in fact "APP_LOG_LEVEL" was not existing but I added it, it it okay? the key is also generated but still nothing worked